Identity Web Application Times Out K8 Cluster
I have the following setup:

6 (tiny) APIs using .NetCore 8
Deployed onto a k8 cluster on Digital Ocean
Use Dapr for messaging between the APIs (this creates a sidecar for each API service)
There is an Nginx load balancer (created using Ingress) in front of all these APIs

I originally had this all running under the lowest plan and I was getting "Thread Starvation" and the cluster would become unresponsive quite quickly (pods in CrashLoopBackOff). I upped the plan significanlty for a test and everything ran fine (I also have had this thread starvation for other projects that usually indicate resource allocation).
I then added a bare bones .NetCore Web Application that uses Duende Identity Server. Since adding this, within 2-3 calls to the aggregator API the whole cluster times out. To be clear, Dapr is not added to this application in the k8 manifests.
I am not able to get logs, not able to delete pods (seemingly a deadlock) and there is nothing noteworthy in the events once I am able to finally load them. I can only delete the pods forcefully while in this state.
Here are the manifests for my Identity Server if that offers any insights:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -f Application/docker-compose.yml -o ./k8s/
    kompose.version: 1.32.0 (765fde254)
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: app-auth-web
  name: app-auth-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: app-auth-web
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -f Application/docker-compose.yml -o ./k8s/
        kompose.version: 1.32.0 (765fde254)
        dapr.io/enabled: "false"
        dapr.io/app-id: "app-auth-web"
        dapr.io/app-port: "8080"
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/app-default: "true"
        io.kompose.service: app-auth-web
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
              value: Production
          image: appauthweb
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - curl --fail http://localhost:80/health || exit 1
            failureThreshold: 3
            periodSeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          name: app-auth-web
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              hostPort: 1252
              protocol: TCP
      restartPolicy: Always

When a simple request is made, the whole cluster just freezes up and it takes about 30 mins to be able to make a request for logs etc. At this point the CPU goes mad (from about 25% to near 100%).
Also note that the initial calls when the Identity server is added via the k8 manifests are very slow indicating something wrong off the bat. There is no issue with this locally though which is what is confusing me - as I said i upped the resources too so I don't think thats an issue (this is bolstered by the apps still being up and not in CrashLoopBackOff like what was happening before).
It is also worth noting that all the other APIs do require the wellknown endpoint from the identity server like specified below:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // Use true in production

     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
         ValidAudiences = jwtOptions.ValidAudiences,
         ValidIssuers = jwtOptions.ValidIssuers,
         ValidateAudience = true,
         ValidateLifetime = true,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         IssuerValidator = (issuer, securityToken, validationParameters) => IssuerHelper.ValidateIssuer(issuer, securityToken, validationParameters),
         IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) =>
         {
             var securityKeys = new List<SecurityKey>();

                 foreach (var endpoint in openIdOptions.WellKnownEndpoints)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                     endpoint,
                     new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
                     new HttpDocumentRetriever { RequireHttps = false }
                 );

                 var config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
                 var signingKeys = config.SigningKeys;

                 securityKeys.AddRange(signingKeys);

                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 // Log?
             }
         }

             return securityKeys;
         }
     };
 });

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on?
